# How to pass data between client and server using SignalR?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have developed a SignalR hub class to pass data through client and server. When Reservation controller Hit I had called `ReservationHub.NotifyCurrentResertiovationToAllClients();` method and it worked fine but it doesn't effect in "Driver view" through pickup partial view. Below mentioned my code. Here I am not able to invoke `updatedClients()` method in my driver view.

I added a brake point and confirmed it was hit in `NotifyCurrentResertiovationToAllClients` method in `ReservationHub` class.
But its came to view nothing happen.

ReservationHub.cs

```
 namespace Taxi_Project
{
public class ReservationHub : Hub
{

    [HubMethodName("NotifyClients")]
    public static void NotifyCurrentResertiovationToAllClients()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ReservationHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updatedClients();
    }
 }
 }
```

HomeController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Driver()
    {
        Pickup();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Pickup()
    {
        List<Reservation> ReseravationList ;
        using (DataContext DbContextHelper = new DataContext())
        {
            ReseravationList = DbContextHelper.Reservations.ToList();
        }
        return PartialView("_Pickup", ReseravationList);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Reservation()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Reservation(Reservation ReservationObj)
    {
        using (DataContext DbContextHelper = new DataContext())
        {
            DbContextHelper.Reservations.Add(ReservationObj);
            DbContextHelper.SaveChanges();
            ReservationHub.NotifyCurrentResertiovationToAllClients();

        }
    return View();}
```

ReservationModel class

```
     public class Reservation
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservationID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReservationType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReservationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

pickup partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<Taxi_Project.Models.Reservation>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReservationType)
</th>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReservationDetails)
</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationType)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationDetails)
</td>
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ReservationID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ReservationID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ReservationID })
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Driver view

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Driver";
}
<h2>Driver</h2>

@Html.Partial("_Pickup")


@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
// Create a proxy to signalr hub on web server. It reference the hub.
var notificationFromHub = $.connection.ReservationHub;
//Connect to signalr hub
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
FetchEmployees();
});

// Notify to client with the recent updates
notificationFromHub.client.updatedClients = function () {
alert('2');
FetchEmployees();
};
});

function FetchEmployees() {
var model = $('#dataTable');
$.ajax({
url: '/home/Pickup',
contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'html'
})
.success(function (result) { model.empty().append(result); })
}

</script>
}
```